# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined [reactjs] with oracle database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code gives me this error :
I see the error

> TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

appearing when I run the project.
I can't find exactly where is the problem
I send 3 different parts of my code that I think most relative to this error.

```
....
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           sts: [
               { code: '1', name: 'فعال' },
               { code: '2', name: 'غیر فعال' }
           ],
           usedin: [
               { code: 'CASETYPE', name: 'نوع ظرف' },
               { code: 'CASEMAT', name: 'جنس' }
           ]
       };
   };
.....
enterAdd = () => {
//console.log("enterAdd");
this.setState({
openForm: true,
editItem: {
srl: Math.max.apply(Math, this.state.infodata.map(({ srl }) => srl)) + 1,
dsc: "",
sts: "1",
usedin: "CASETYPE",
uDateTime: "",
uauserSrl: 1
},
editMode: false,
})
}
<Column
field="usedin"
title="محل استفاده"
width="120px"
cell={(props) => (
<td> 
<div>
{props.dataItem[props.field] ? this.state.usedin.find(
({ code }) => code === props.dataItem[props.field]).name : ""}
</div>
</td>
)}
/>
```

Comment: At first glance, I'd say there aren't any results from your `find`. Are you sure `usedin` has such a value?

Comment: `this.state.usedin.find(({ code }) => code === props.dataItem[props.field])` appears to be undefined at least once. What is your `usedin` state and what are any functions/etc... that operate on *that* state?

Comment: can you show us the result of the console..`console.log(this.state.usedin)` and `console.logprops.dataItem[props.field])`

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

It seems that `this.state.usedin.find(({ code }) => code === props.dataItem[props.field])` sometimes isn't able to find a match and is returning `undefined`. The error is thrown when you attempt to access properties of an undefined object.

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no
> values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

## Solution

Handle gracefully when the `array.prototype.find` function returns undefined when it doesn't find a match.

Solution 1 - Search first and then conditionally render via ternary.

```
const usedin = props.dataItem[props.field] &&
  this.state.usedin.find(({ code }) => code === props.dataItem[props.field]);

<td> 
  <div>
    {usedin ? usedin.name : ""}
  </div>
</td>
```

Solution 2 - Search first and use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish Coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

```
const usedin = props.dataItem[props.field] &&
  this.state.usedin.find(({ code }) => code === props.dataItem[props.field]);

<td> 
  <div>
    {usedin?.name || ""}
  </div>
</td>
```

**Note:** If you've a reasonable guarantee that `dataItem` is available on the `props` object then you can also skip the null check. In this case you would simply be comparing `code === undefined` which may be ok for your use-case.

```
const usedin = this.state.usedin.find(
  ({ code }) => code === props.dataItem[props.field]
);
```